# High Voltage Triac Control

Tags: microcontroller, control, power-electronics, triac, induction-motor

I'm trying to control a **universal motor** run from a **240V** power supply using a **micro-controller**. There is a existing PCB that uses a potentiometer to vary the speed that I am trying to replace. I've identified the triac but the rest of the parts are covered, I've assumed it is something like this:

[image: Current Triac/Diac Circuit]

I've been looking into IC solutions, BJTs, MOSFETs, etc to replace the potentiometer but am struggling to find a solution that I can fully understand and that will simulate. The micro controller will be an Arduino. The motor power is up to **around 750 W**.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated as I've spent so much time reading around the subject but am not confident with any of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a particularly easy circuit to control through a safe galvanically-isolated connection. Normally the approach used in a production design would be to couple the microcontroller to the mains via an optocoupled zero-crossing detector and then trigger the triac through an opto-triac. The power would be a function of the delay between the zero crossing and the triac trigger.

If you really want to use that "light dimmer" circuit, it's possible with a light-dependent resistor (LDR) and a variable light source. LDRs may be hard to buy in some countries because they contain cadmium which is not RoHS compliant.

By the way, I'm not sure what you intend by that voltage source but it has a rather uncommon RMS voltage of 170V. If you intend to have 240VAC RMS @ 50Hz, you should use about 340V for the peak voltage (240\$\times\sqrt 2\$).

Comment: Have you got an example part number / circuit diagram of the zero-crossing detector you mentioned? Are these the right thing: http://onecall.farnell.com/triac-output-optocouplers. And how about http://onecall.farnell.com/excelitas-tech/vt90n1/ldr-200kohm-80mw-vt900-series/dp/2293503 for the LDR

Comment: The zero crossing detector is not a single component- it's a compound circuit. You can find examples in this SE as well as elsewhere. That LDR is the right idea, but of course it needs a much higher voltage rating for use on a 340V peak circuit.